# After scraping I can not write the text to a text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-files, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the prices from a website and it's working but... I can't write the result to a text.file.
this is my python code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.futbin.com/stc/cheapest"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find("div", {"class":"d-flex row col-md-9 px-0"})

name =("example")
f =open(name + '.txt', "a")

f.write(price.text)
```

This is not working but if I print it instead of try to write it to a textfile it's working. I have searched for a long  time but don't understand it. I think it must be a string to write to a text file but don't know how to change the ouput to a string.

Comment: your code works onm my test. maybe you would need to call f.close() after f.write()

Answer (score 1):

You're getting error due to unicode character.
Try to add `encoding='utf-8'` property while opening a file.

Also your code gives a bit messy output. Try this instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.futbin.com/stc/cheapest"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, "html.parser")
rows = soup.find("div", {"class":"d-flex row col-md-9 px-0"})
prices = rows.findAll("span",{"class":"price-holder-row"})
names = rows.findAll("div",{"class":"name-holder"})
price_list = []
name_list = []
for price in prices:
    price_list.append(price.text.strip("\n "))
for name in names:
    name_list.append(name.text.split()[0])
name =("example")
with open(f"{name}.txt",mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for name, price in zip(name_list,price_list):
        f.write(f"{name}:{price}\n")
```

Comment: Great! Thank you this really helps me a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. You can thank me by giving an upvote. Written thank you's are not allowed on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I can not upvote because I am new......